# Matching a substring using a regular expression in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

Regular expressions are really not my forte and I am trying to learn. Struggling with this one at the moment.

```
<fraglink id="230681395" resid="1057000484">
```

I have a file with loads of text in it, and every now and then bits like the above appear in it. I want to get the number in between the quotes after `resid=`.

Is some sort of look ahead / behind required here?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want a regex like:

```
resid="([0-9]+)"
```

And to grab `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your content looks like XML, you should probably **not use** a regular expression to grab your desired value. If you share your whole file we will show you how to select the value properly using XPath for example.

However, if you want to use a regular expression for training purposes, try this:

```
$content = Get-Content 'your_file_path' -raw
[regex]::Match($content, '\bresid="([^"]+)').Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a lookahead (`(?<=pattern)`), your pattern could look like:

```
(?<=resid=")\d+
```

With `Regex.Match()`:

```
$id = [regex]::Match($inputString,'(?<=resid=")\d+').Value
```